# MS Flow is raising this error :- 'XrmSystemUserDisabled'. Error Message: 'The CDS system user record representing user is disabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, microsoft-flow

When the MS flow runs it raises the following error on a "Start and Wait for Approval" action:-

```
The request failed. Error code: 'XrmSystemUserDisabled'. Error Message: 'The CDS system user record representing user 'admin.user@***.com' is disabled. Please ask a database administrator to enable this user.'.
```

Here is a screen shot of my Flow and the error i am getting:-
[image]

now the admin.user@***.com is our global admin and is enabled,,, so why the error is saying that the user account is disabled... any advice? Also seems all the Connections are working well as follow:-
[image]

so not sure what is going on?

Comment: You can try deleting the approval connection and recreating it as it seems little older. Does your flow use any CDS actions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you encountered the following error？

[image: Disabled]

This issue occurs when the last Flow license (or Office license that includes Flow) expires in your tenant. In this situation, the Flow service is disabled in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).

**Please follow these steps:**

***Note: These steps can be performed only by the tenant admin.***

1.Go to Azure Active Directory admin center

2.Click on **Azure Active Directory** in the navigation bar
[image: AD]

3.Click on **Enterprise applications**, then go to **All applications**
[image]

4.Paste **7df0a125-d3be-4c96-aa54-591f83ff541c** into the filter input.
[image]

5.Select **Microsoft Flow Service**, and then select **Properties**.

6.Make sure that the Enabled for users to sign-in? option is set to **Yes**.

7.Click **Save**.

========================

Have a nice day！